# What can a quantum query to a function do?

Tags: complexity-theory, quantum-computing

The $n$-qubit Hadamard gate acts as,

$$H (\otimes^n \vert 0 \rangle ) = \otimes ^n ( H | 0 \rangle ) = \otimes ^n ( \frac { |0\rangle + |1\rangle }{\sqrt{2} } ) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n} } \sum_{x \in \{ 0,1\}^n} |x\rangle $$

So it is capable of producing the uniform superposition state over an exponential number of states in what is to be seen as a ``single" step.

- Now if one is given a boolean function $f$ then how is it that the above uniform superposition state can be converted into   $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n} } \sum_{x \in \{ 0,1\}^n} f(x) |x\rangle$ by a ``single query to $f$ in superposition" ?

  Can someone give a mathematical or a gate picture of this ''single query to $f$ in superposition" ? What is the unitary operator which corresponds to this ''single query to $f$ in superposition"  ?

---

A part of this confusion arises because I am under the impression that if kets are indexed by elements of $\{0,1\}^n$ then a ''single" quantum query to a Boolean valued function $f$ is ``by definition" a transformation of the form  $\vert x \rangle \vert y \rangle \rightarrow \vert x \rangle \vert y \oplus f(x) \rangle$ or which is often thought of as the operator $O_f(x)$ acting as $O_f(x) \vert y \rangle =  \vert y \oplus f(x) \rangle$

But I can't see the transformation in the question as a any combination of $O_f(x)$ kind of operators!

Answer (score 5):

the gate $f$ performs the transformation 
$$\rvert x\rangle \rvert0\rangle \to \rvert x\rangle \rvert 0\oplus f(x)\rangle, $$

but $0$ is idempotent for $\oplus$ so you simply get $\rvert x\rangle \rvert f(x)\rangle$.
Now, by linearity, if you input a superposition instead of a basis states, you'll get a superposition of the "answers", e.g.,

$$\frac1{\sqrt2}(\rvert 0\rangle \rvert0\rangle+\rvert1\rangle |0\rangle) \to \frac1{\sqrt2}(\rvert 0\rangle \rvert f(0)\rangle+\rvert 1\rangle \rvert f(1)\rangle)$$

Then, if you start with a Hadamard, and get an equal superposition of all basis states, you end up with a superposition of all possible "answers".
$$\frac1{N} \sum_x \rvert x\rangle \rvert 0 \rangle \to \frac1{N} \sum_x \rvert x\rangle \rvert f(x) \rangle.$$

The fact that $x$ or $0$ are in fact a "string" over $\{0,1\}$ doesn't make any difference - treat them as a single quantum system of higher dimension (or treat each qubit as a separate function $f_i$ where $f_1()f_2()\cdots f_n()=f()$ are the bit-wise functions.

Comment: Your transformation $$\frac1{N} \sum_x \rvert x\rangle \rvert 0 \rangle \to \frac1{N} \sum_x \rvert x\rangle \rvert f(x) \rangle.$$ is not the same as what I see being the standard meaning of ''single query to $f$ in superposition" which is given as,  $$ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n} } \sum_{x \in \{ 0,1\}^n} |x\rangle  \to \frac{1}{\sqrt{2^n} } \sum_{x \in \{ 0,1\}^n} f(x) |x\rangle$$

Comment: They can be equivalent. Assume f(x) is binary (e.g. when the oracle is yes/no, as in search algorithms). Then one definition is $$|x\rangle|y\rangle \to |x\rangle|y\oplus f(x)\rangle.$$ But let $|y\rangle=(|0\rangle-|1\rangle)/\sqrt2$ and see the magic: if $f(x)=0$ nothing happens, but if $f(x)=1$, the outputs is now $(|1\rangle-|0\rangle)/\sqrt2=-|y\rangle$, and you get that the oracle is equivalent to $$|x\rangle|y\rangle \to (-1)^{f(x)}|x\rangle|y\rangle.$$ See also Nielsen and Chuang, Chap 6.

Comment: I am not sure you are getting the issue here. The two transformations that I wrote in the first comment are possible in two non-isomorphic vector spaces. Even if $f$ is Boolean valued, the first one is a transformation in a space of dimension $2^{n+1}$ but the later is a transformation in a vector space of dimension $2^n$. An operator which can effect the first can't effect the second. The two can't be "equal" definitions of what a "single quantum query to $f$" means.

Comment: (Given a system of $n$ qubits I would believe that there exists an universal definition of what is the operator that effects a "single quantum query to $f$")

Comment: I believe you give to much credit to a notion of "single quantum query". It is not set in stone. It is whatever people use and whatever makes sense. I don't see the problem you are trying to state in your comment - if you ignore the second subsystem (the "y" part) the two transformations are equivalent (not *equal*, but *equivalent*). In my understanding (which may be wrong), when the funciton acts onto the same space I'd call it a gate (e.g., the Fourier  gate). To me, a query is of the form I have in my answer. Again, these are conventions rather than "truth". We can continue in the [chat].